# pattern matching parse float error

Tags: rust

I have this:

```
struct Test {
    amount: f32
}

fn main() {

    let amnt: String = "9.95".to_string();
    let test = Test {
        amount: match amnt.parse() {
            Ok(num) => num.unwrap(),
            Err(e) => 0f32
        }
    };

}
```

and it's causing an error:

```
error: the type of this value must be known in this context
       Ok(num) => num.unwrap(),
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How do I cast `num` to fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you're already pattern matching on `Ok()`, you don't need to call `unwrap()`; `num` is already of type `f32`.

This compiles fine:

```
struct Test {
    amount: f32
}

fn main() {

    let amnt: String = "9.95".to_string();
    let test = Test {
        amount: match amnt.parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(e) => 0f32
        }
    };

}
```

You can also use `Result::unwrap_or()` instead:

```
Test {
   amount: amnt.parse().unwrap_or(0.0)
}
```